# What is the difference between the UNION and CONCATENATION operators in terms of performance?

Tags: oracle, database-performance, sql-tuning

Sometimes, it can be seen CONCATENATION step in the Explain Plan.

I wonder what is the difference between union and concatenation operators in terms of performance tuning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, `UNION` and `CONCATENATION` are subtly different.

`CONCATENATION` is equivalent to `UNION-ALL`. This combines the input tables and returns all the rows.

`UNION` combines the input tables. Then returns the *distinct* rows.

So `UNION` has an extra sort/distinct operation compared to `CONCATENATION`. How big this effect is depends on your data set.

You'll see `CONCATENATION` when the optimizer does an OR expansion. But note that from Oracle Database 12.2, [this has changed](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion):

> - CONCATENATION is replaced with UNION-ALL.
> - Each UNION-ALL branch can be subject to further query transformations, if applicable. This is not possible with
>     CONCATENATION.
> - Parallel queries can execute UNION-ALL branches concurrently. Again, this is not possible with CONCATENATION.

So `UNION-ALL` can come up with better plans for each operation below it. And run these at the same (if using parallel). So in many cases this will be faster than `CONCATENATION`.

Answer (score 0):

A UNION has to remove duplicates, which is expensive. CONCATENATION is the step that happens when you do a UNION ALL (which does not remove duplicates, hence is cheaper).